# UWP - Get location coordinates explicitly via GPS Sensor in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, gps, iot

I'm working on UWP Application to get the GPS coordinates for Windows Device.
Normally UWP Location API fetch the location data from different sources like if there is GPS available, it will use GPS to get the location information other wise it will give results from Wifi and Other internet connection that is currently available.

this is the code used to get location coordinates.

```
Geoposition geoposition = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
                    double altitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Altitude;
                    double latitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
                    double longitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
                    string positionSource = geoposition.Coordinate.PositionSource.ToString();
```

// Wifi or GPS or Other Internet connection

My device GPS is also available but all the result I'm getting through this code are based on Internet Wifi connection. 
Is there a way to set the location information source manually for the UWP app in C# to get all the information explicitly from GPS installed in Device ?
I've searched a lot but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Can you explain the iot tag?

Comment: we are currently working on IoT project . this task is a part of that project that's why i mentioned.

Comment: That could be the case, but I think its not relevant for the question, because it hasn't to do anything with iot

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the driver of the GPS sensor you used provides the GPS data in the correct format to Geolocator. If not, you need to implement a driver for your specific GPS sensor, or communicate with the sensor via owned interface, or contact with the supplier. If the driver provides data in correct format to Geolocator, you need not to set the source.

In location services architecture,the first layer of the location services architecture consists of hardware in the device. This includes the GPS receiver, Wi-Fi, and the cellular radio. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation).

Comment: I guess there is some problem with driver of device. that's why it is not fetching data through GPS sensor.

Comment: Can you communicate with the GPS sensor to get the output data manually? If the GPS sensor provides serial port communication, you can retrieve the data from GPS senor.